# Measuring performance of android browser

Tags: android, browser, webkit, performance

I would like to know if there is a way/hook which I can enable in android webkit to measure performance of the browser when loading sites. For example chromium on android has the "remote debugger" in the developer tools which can let me do that. In ICS the stock browser is webkit based I believe and I was looking at the code to figure out if this was possible, even in a simplistic way than the whole remote debugger utility.

Any performance characterstic like round trip time, network charactersitics, time to load resources etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Weinre to do this: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Pretty fantastic stuff.